# Combine various activities into one cell when the condition (date) is met google sheet

Tags: excel, windows, google-sheets, database-design, google-sheets-formula

Good day!

I'm seeking for your kind assistance pls. What is the right formula to arrive the below output? thank you in advance.

```
Data
Ref   Activity 1   Activity 2   Activity 3
001  23-Oct-2021   25-Oct-2021  5-Nov-2021
002  25-Oct-2021   30-Oct-2021  5-Nov-2021
003  25-Oct-2021   5-Nov-2021   6-Nov-2021

Output
  23-Oct-2021        
001 - Activity 1  

 25-Oct-2021         
001 - Activity 2    
002 - Activity 1    
003 - Activity 1
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Reading [ask] and [repro] should help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B2:D="",," ♣"&TO_TEXT(B2:D)&"♦"&A2:A&" - "&B1:D1)), "♦"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"))), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♣")), 
 "where Col1 is not null offset 1", 0))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(C4:E6="",,TO_TEXT(C4:E6)&"♠♣♦"&B4:B6&" - "&C3:E3)), "♦"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), 
 " ", CHAR(13)),,9^9)), "♣"))), " ", CHAR(10)), "♠", ))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. it's working.  ^_^. I will just figure out how to shoot this in a calendar but I'll try to do it. thank you soooo much.. *_*

Comment: here's my working file.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHgsxcxsLJsnfwlMnk0CdaGSrrkp9Ubdyb5OTwvKuMI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I clicked the checked mark but I cant cast a vote yet. Can I ask one more thing pls? the output should be actually in a calendar form. I tried to figure out how to do it using textjoin but it slows down the file. the output should be separated per date. thank you in advance.

Comment: @ArchieUni answer updated